# execute first time window.setInterval in two seconds and then call it every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

I have a function inside js:

```
(function($){
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {     
         index = 0;
         window.setInterval(function () {
            if (index > 10){ 
               index = 0;
            }    
            myFunction("so1", "flipping-right");
            myFunction("so2", "flipping-left");        
            myFunction("so3", "flipping-top");
            myFunction("so4", "flipping-bottom");
            myFunction("so5", "flipping-right");
            i++;
         }, 2000); 
        });

        myFunction = function (id, effect ) { 
              $('#' + id).toggleClass(effect);
        } 

   });
})(jQuery);
```

How could I  execute it **only the first time** with parameter **"2 seconds"**

```
window.setInterval(function () {...}, 2000);
```

and from that every call to it, change the parameter to  8 seconds

```
window.setInterval(function () {...}, 8000);
```

so resuming, first time execute it with parameter 2000, and then everytime 8000 ?

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2wxX/5/)

Comment: First use `setTimeout` with `2000` parameter, then `setInterval` with `8000`

Comment: Or do `setTimeout` with `2000`, then inside the function, `clearTimeout` and then `setTimeout` with `10000`.

Comment: why do you need `(function($){......})(jQuery);`? I mean, is there a specific reason you put it there for? IMO, you don't need another closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the first call in a `setTimeout` with 2000 parameter, then put the `setInterval` call with 8000 parameter at the end of your `setTimeout` function.